# SQL - How to equally assigned records to Skil matrix table using stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-optimization

I want to use a stored procedure for assigning records to each person.

These are my tables:

**tblTransaction**:

```
    ID  Owner     Country   Region    Vendor    Description
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    1   NULL      Country1  Region1   Vendor2   
    4   NULL      Country1  Region1   NULL  
    7   NULL      Country1  Region1   Vendor2   
    10  NULL      Country1  Region1   NULL  
    13  NULL      Country1  Region2   Vendor3   
    16  NULL      Country1  Region2   Vendor3   Description1
    19  NULL      Country1  Region2   Vendor3   Description1
    2   NULL      Country2  Region1   Vendor1   Description1
    5   NULL      Country2  Region2   Vendor1   
    8   NULL      Country2  Region1   Vendor1   
    11  NULL      Country2  Region1   Vendor2   Description1
    14  NULL      Country2  Region1   NULL  
    17  NULL      Country2  Region1   Vendor2   
    20  NULL      Country3  Region1   NULL  
    3   NULL      Country3  Region2   Vendor3   
    6   NULL      Country3  Region2   Vendor3   Description1
    9   NULL      Country3  Region2   NULL  
    12  NULL      Country3  Region2   NULL  
    15  NULL      Country3  Region1   Vendor1   
    18  NULL      Country3  Region2   Vendor1
```

**tblSkillMatrix**

```
Owner   IsTeamLead  Country     Vendor   Region     Description
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Person1      N      Country1    Vendor1  Region1    
Person2      Y      Country2    Vendor2  Region2    Description1
Person3      N      Country2    Vendor3  Region2    
Person4      Y      Country1    Vendor4  Region1    Description1
Person5      N      Country1    Vendor4  Region1
```

I need to update `tblTransaction` based on the condition in `tblSkillMatrix` and once done, insert it into table `tblAssignment` which is my 3rd table.

Below are the requirements:

- Assign ID to TeamLead(if IsTeamLead = 'Y'). Description = 'Description1'
- If `Country` does not exist in `tblSkillMatrix` and if `Vendor` is NULL, assign IDs equally to TeamLeads only regardless of its `Country`
- Assign max of 2 transactions to `TeamLead` per `Country`
- Non-TeamLead must be equally assigned per `Country`
- For Non-TeamLead, if `Country` does not exist in `tblSkillMatrix`, use `Region` instead. Needs to be equally distributed.

The results should be like this:

**tblAssignment** (output)

```
ID  Owner     Country   Region    Vendor    Description
----------------------------------------------------------------
1   Person1   Country1  Region1   Vendor2   
4   Person1   Country1  Region1   NULL  
7   Person5   Country1  Region1   Vendor2   
10  Person5   Country1  Region1   NULL  
13  Person4   Country1  Region2   Vendor3   
16  Person2   Country1  Region2   Vendor3   Description1
19  Person2   Country1  Region2   Vendor3   Description1
2   Person2   Country2  Region1   Vendor1   Description1
5   Person2   Country2  Region2   Vendor1   
8   Person2   Country2  Region1   Vendor1   
11  Person4   Country2  Region1   Vendor2   Description1
14  Person3   Country2  Region1   NULL  
17  Person3   Country2  Region1   Vendor2   
20  Person4   Country3  Region1   NULL  
3   Person3   Country3  Region2   Vendor3   
6   Person4   Country3  Region2   Vendor3   Description1
9   Person4   Country3  Region2   NULL  
12  Person2   Country3  Region2   NULL  
15  Person1   Country3  Region1   Vendor1   
18  Person3   Country3  Region2   Vendor1
```

Comment: Tag which database you are using, and remember to also include your attempt at assigning the owners.